# Pebble.js Geolocation not Storing Location Globally

Tags: javascript, pebble-sdk, pebble-js

I am very new to programming Pebble watches. I have been doing it for 3 hours now. I am stuck trying to assign the latitude and longitude to variables. Hopefully this is just a simple Javascript issue and not a Pebble SDK related issue.

Here is my code:

```
var lat;
var lon;

var myAPIKey = REDACTED;
var city = 'Boston';

function success(pos) {
console.log('lat= ' + pos.coords.latitude + ' lon= ' + pos.coords.longitude);
lat = pos.coords.latitude;
lon = pos.coords.longitude;
}

function error(err) {
console.log('location error (' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
}

// Choose options about the data returned
var options = {
enableHighAccuracy: true,
maximumAge: 10000,
timeout: 10000
};

// Request current position
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
console.log(lat+'||||'+lon);
```

When I run the code on the CloudPebble Emulator this the log info:

```
[PHONE] pebble-app.js:?: undefined||||undefined
[PHONE] pebble-app.js:?: lat= 39.0437 lon= -77.4875
```

Am I not storing the latitude and longitude correctly. I want to use the data for global use. You can see that it doesnt store the `lat` and `lon` values, but it does actually run from the `consol.log` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since determining the position can take a while, `getCurrentPosition()` doesn't run synchronously. Instead it takes one function (the `success` parameter) to call when it (eventually) managed to acquire the location, and one function (the `error` parameter) when it failed to do so (GPS or Wifi can't be reached or is turned off, etc).

Your code *does* store the values into your `lat` and `lon` variables properly, but this only happens at a later point. Or in other words: Your

```
console.log(lat+'||||'+lon);
```

is called *before* the `success` function runs. At that time the values are not yet filled.

This is a common JavaScript approach to deal with long running operations. Other objects like `XMLHTTPRequest` work exactly the same way.